# Apache redirects to localhost instead of server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, localhost

I managed to restore on a virtual machine an ubuntu apache server that was done by someone else. When I open it though (`http://192.168.1.15`), index.php loads ok but there are no images. It turns out that my browser (from another computer on the same LAN) is looking for images in `http://localhost/images` and doesn't find them.
I am not familiar with this, but it seems like there is a variable somewhere that should translate to the server's address instead of `localhost`. Where is this exactly and how do I change it ?

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Apache 2.4
MySql 5.7.25
PHP 7.0

Edit:

`apache2ctl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   185.168.1.138 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
*:8001                 185.168.1.138 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:37)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8001>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Part of index.html produced

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/websrv/assets/front_end/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/websrv/assets/front_end/css/custom.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/websrv/assets/front_end/js/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-BpNbgh9B+Y2QKtz3Rn7W1mgPxhU9K/ScTsAP7hUlbW39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/websrv/assets/front_end/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZE6Spejh4U12d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSgFEpi1MquVdAyjUcr5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/websrv/assets/back_end/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<title>websrv | User | Login</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .custom_form label.error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>

[..]
```

`index.php`

```
<?php
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
case 'development':
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
break;

case 'testing':
case 'production':
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    }
    else
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
break;
default:
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
    exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';
$view_folder = '';
if (defined('STDIN'))
{
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
}
if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
{
    $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
else
{
    $system_path = strtr(
        rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
define('BASEPATH', $system_path);
define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH));
if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $application_folder = $_temp;
    }
    else
    {
        $application_folder = strtr(
            rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
}
elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
{
    $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr(
        trim($application_folder, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    );
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}
define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
{
    $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
}
elseif (is_dir($view_folder))
{
    if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $view_folder = $_temp;
    }
    else
    {
        $view_folder = strtr(
            rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
}
elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
{
    $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr(
        trim($view_folder, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    );
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}

define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Comment: You should edit your question and add the configuration of Apache's `<VirtualHost>` (probably in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`) and the output of `apache2ctl -S`. Without that information it is difficult to guess why your **index.php** is generating URLs starting with `http://localhost`.

Comment: thanks for the help, I didn't know where to start

Comment: If the script does not always use `http://localhost` in the generated URLs, adding a [ServerName](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) directive to the `<VirtualHost>`'s might help. Although everything depends on the script. Usually programmers use only relative or absolute URI paths in links, not URLs.

Comment: Actually from what I can see, it always uses `http://localhost` in URL-s. Adding info on the question again

Comment: What you show is an already generated `index.html`. You need to look into `index.php` and the included files to see what code generated it.

Comment: I added `index.php`, but i think it's about setting smth in my ubuntu vm rather than the code, since it was working on the original server

Comment: You should flag your own question and ask the moderators to migrate it to StackOverflow, since this is a programming problem. More precisely it depends on the way [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/) generates URLs.

Comment: That was exactly it. In `application/config/config.php` :: `elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='192.168.1.15') { $config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://192.168.1.15/'; } ` Thanks a lot. Now I hope moderators will reopen the question so one of us can post the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this same concern when setting up **VtigerCRM** on a Windows machine.

I had setup WAMP server and my configuration all looked fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/vtigercrm"
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/myvtigercrm"
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to access the website over a browser, I am redirected to http://localhost/vtigercrm, even though I had specified my web address in the Apache configuration file.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Apparently, **vtigercrm** has a configuration file called `config.inc.php` which can be found in the root folder of your vtigercrm setup/folder

**Note**: You may need to enable **Show hidden files** in order to see the file, or at best just do a find/search inside your vtigercrm folder for a file named `config.inc.php`.

Next, open the file and modify the line below. Replace:

```
$site_URL = 'http://localhost/vtigercrm';
```

with:

```
$site_URL = 'http://domain-name/';
```

Or

```
$site_URL = 'http://your-server-IP/';
```

Save and exit the file.

Finally, restart all services using Wamp.

Now your setup should work fine.

Resources: [[SOLVED] Vtiger : Redirect to 127.0.0.1](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=129684)